# QT qmake instructions in defines?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

is it possible to use QT qmake instructions in defines?

I tried to create an QT Plugin Interface class by a define:

```
#define PLUGIN(NAME) \
class NAME ## Plugin : public QObject, public IPluginInterface \
{ \
Q_OBJECT \
Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID "org.my.Plugins" FILE "NAME ## .json") \
Q_INTERFACES(IPluginInterface) \
public: \
virtual ~NAME ## PluginInterface(){} \
NAME ## PluginInterface(){} \
/* implementation of interface */
}; \
NAME ## Plugin NAME ## plugininterface;
```

but after running qmake and make my program does not load the plugin.
Message is: Plugin verification data mismatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not (directly) possible, as `moc` does not do preprocessing. See the relevant section in the [Qt docs for `moc`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#limitations).

You might get away with it if you run the preprocessor manually (with some hacking not to expand `moc`-used macros like `Q_OBJECT`) and then run `moc` on the preprocessed file. But that would require significnat support in your buildsystem.